# Give parameters to a function called by setInterval

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following function:

```
<script>
    var count=900;
    var countM;
    var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer()
    {
        count=count-1;
        countM=Math.floor(count/60);
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }

        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById("timer"+i).innerHTML=countM+"mins. "+(count%60)+ " secs"; // watch for spelling
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I am displaying it like this:

```
<span id="<?php echo "timer".$theCounter; ?>"></span>
$theCounter++;
```

The problem its that I want to call it giving it a parameter, which will be `count` and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You didn't post how and where you call the function. I also don't understand how a `span` element can call a function.

Comment: well the span element its displaying the timer, its a countdown timer, im adding $theCounter variable to display different timers!

Comment: Ah. I also noticed the `var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);` part in your code now. So, interacting with the `span` element doesn't start the function, it's called right away. The title of your question suggested otherwise and got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *'I want to call it giving it a parameter, which will be "count"'*

Something like the following:

```
function createTimer(count) {
    var countM,
        counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer()
    {
        count -= 1;
        countM = Math.floor(count/60);
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            document.getElementById("timer"+i).innerHTML=countM+"mins. "+(count%60)+ " secs"; 
        }
    }
}
```

...will give you a function, `createTimer()`, that you can call with a parameter for the count:

```
createTimer(900);
```

If you're saying you want different spans to have different counters then you can do this:

```
function createTimer(count, elementID) {
   // code exactly the same as above function except
   // remove the `for` loop and just reference the elementID
   // passed into the function:
   document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML=countM+"mins. "+(count%60)+ " secs"; 
}

createTimer(900, 'timer1');
createTimer(200, 'timer2');
// etc.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dUTk3/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem its that im displayin the timer on a table in my webpage, using the <span>, how can i call the function on php? thanks

Comment: @user2465233: This is a JavaScript function. You cannot call it in PHP. Just place `createTimer(900);` after the function definition. If you want to use a PHP variable value instead of `900`, do the same as you do in the HTML: `createTimer(<?php echo $count; ?>);`.

Comment: oh!, that semms to have logic, let me try it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var counter = window.setInterval(function() {
    timer('parameter');
}, 1000);
```

I do not see what is the relationship between the javascript and PHP parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function prototype to create a function with default parameters.

```
timer.bind(null,count-1);
```

The first argument is function context (null means global), optional following parameters is set tho function arguments from left. The result is new function. So in your code:

```
function timer(count) {
    console.log(count); // do some stuff
    if(count>0) setTimeout(timer.bind(null,count-1),1000);
}

timer(10); // counts from 10 to 0 in 1s interval
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YR2yG/)